# Solve $\;y'' + y' − 6y = 60δ(t − 2),\;$ with $\,y(0) = 1,\; y′(0) = 4.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $\;y'' + y' − 6y = 60δ(t − 2),\;$ with $\,y(0) = 1,\; y′(0) = 4.$

Comment: How far have you got?

Comment: i know to solve y'' + y' -6y = 0 i can't solve this one

Comment: i know to solve y'' + y' -6y = 0
r^2 + r - 6 =0
r=-3 , 2

Comment: @rohit: Do you know if $r_1, r_2$ are two **real** roots of the characteristic equation, then the solution of homogeneous equation is of the form $y(t)=C_1e^{r_1t}+C_2e^{r_2t}$?

Comment: yes @SwapnilTripathi i know that. Here we will use laplace?

Comment: Yes, I guess it will work. Have you tried it?

Comment: i dnt know that can u help me?

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/IVPWithLaplace.aspx Do you follow example 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to consider the Laplace transform of both sides i.e.
$$\mathcal{L}(y''+y'-6y)=\mathcal{L}(60\delta(t-2))$$
$$\Leftrightarrow$$
$$s^2Y(s)-sy(0)-y'(0)+sY(s)-y(0)-6Y(s)=60e^{-2s}$$
where $$\mathcal{L}(f)(s)=\int^{\infty}_{0}f(x)e^{-sx}\,dx$$
Substituting for $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)=4$ one finds 
$$Y(s)(s^2+s-6)=60e^{-2s}+s+5\Leftrightarrow Y(s)=\frac{60e^{-2s}+s+5}{s^2+s-6}$$
However you are interested in $y(t)$ therefore one can take the inverse Laplace transform of $Y(s)$ i.e.
$$y(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}(Y)(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int^{\gamma+i\infty}_{\gamma-i\infty}\frac{60e^{-2s}+s+5}{s^2+s-6}\cdot e^{st}\,ds$$
The last integral can be computed using the typical Bromwich contour and applying residue theorem.
$$y(t)=\frac{1}{5}e^{-3t-4}(60(e^{5t}-e^{10})H(t-2)+e^4(7e^{5t}-2))$$
where $H(t)$ is the Heaviside step function.

Answer (score 3):

For $t \lt 2$, the solution should be clear (the RHS is zero):

$$y_-(t) = \frac{7}{5} e^{2 t}-\frac{2}{5} e^{-3 t}$$

For $t \gt 2$, however, the solution changes due to the impulse.  However, since the impulse is zero when $t \gt 2$, we may assume the same general solution:

$$y_+(t) = A \, e^{2 t} + B \, e^{-3 t}$$

We find the constants $A$ and $B$ through two conditions:

1) The full solution must be continuous at $t=2$, i.e., 
$$y_-(2)=y_+(2)$$

2) The derivative of the full solution experiences a jump discontinuity at $t=2$ given by

$$y'_+(2) - y'_-(2) = 60$$

This latter condition may be derived by integrating the differential equation between $[2-\epsilon, 2+\epsilon]$ and taking the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$.

These conditions produce two equations for the two unknowns $A$ and $B$.  I get

$$A = \frac{7}{5}  + 12 e^{-4}$$
$$B = -\frac{2}{5} - 12 e^6 $$

The solution then becomes

$$y(t) =  \frac{7}{5} e^{2 t}-\frac{2}{5} e^{-3 t} + 12 \theta(t-2) \left (e^{2 (t-2)} - e^{-3 (t-2)} \right ) $$

where $\theta$ is the Heaviside step function.

Comment: This is a nice and intuitive solution.

Comment: @SimonS: thanks.  It should come as no surprise to anyone that's seen a Green's function.